# missing blank space and special character in php array output

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter to create a web application and I got a problem with the printed name of the category.

Some category are saved in database with name like "shoes & bags"
the results in the front-end is "shoes".
What I am doing is that:

Model:

```
function displayCategory(){
      $result = $this->db->get('category');
      return $result->result_array(); 
  }
```

Controller:

```
$pelcst_d['categorylist'] = $this->category->displayCategory();
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($category as $key => $value) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $value['category']; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Maybe not related, but Is `personal_closest` is name of your model? If yes, why you passing `user_id` parameter in `displayCategory()` while the argument is not set in the model. Might help to answer your main questions.

Comment: Sorry i've update the code was from another function.

Comment: You might need to do a `var_dump($category);` too see if your full category name is available in your variable. If its there, you know problem is in displaying but if not, you need to update your query/model.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand (`&`) is a special character in HTML. It introduces a [`character entity`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview). In order to display the ampersand's literal value, its character entity (`&amp;`) must be used.

If `$value['category'] == 'shoes & bags'` then the HTML generated in the view is:

```
<li>shoes & bags</li>
```

but the correct representation of it in HTML is:

```
<li>shoes &amp; bags</li>
```

Depending on some factors, the browser can fix your error (read `&amp;` instead of `&` in order to render it as `&`) or ignore it (read `& bags`, cannot interpret it as a valid character entity and drops it).

The correct code is:

```
    <li><?php echo(htmlspecialchars($value['category'])); ?></li>
```

**Always** use the PHP function [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to properly encode the values you get from user input or from the database when you generate HTML content.